# How to call api in ionic framework using react?

Tags: reactjs, api, ionic-framework, react-hooks, ionic-react

I'm trying to fetch API using this but it's not working.

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";          
  const response = await fetch(url);      
  const data = await response.json();      
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific - is anything being logged at all?

Comment: Use Axois Api: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 0):

You could use axios to make an API call.

The sample code is as below

```
const authenticateUser = async  (username: string, password: string) : Promise<boolean> => {

    const loginData = {
        "Username": username,
        "Password": password
    }

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: "https://website.com/api/services"
    })

    const resp = await api.post("/ValidateUserPost", loginData)

    if(resp.data != null && resp.data.userId != null && resp.data.userId > 0){               
        return true
    } 
    else
        return false
};
```